# PHP insert <div> and line shift after every 10th DB element in foreach loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

Overall I would like to echo all elements of the DB table 'products' as buttons on a row, and for each 10th element, a lineshift should be implemented. Each line should be surrounded by a specific  ().

I have printed the code I have been working with to do this:

products_backend.php:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
$stmt->execute();

$count = $stmt->rowCount();

if($count > 1){

    $table_row = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $i = 0;

    foreach($table_row as $data) {
        $i++;

    ?>
                    <div class="col-md-1 cash_register pants">
                    <button class="table_add" value="Bukser">
                        <h4><?php echo $data['product_name']; ?></h4>
                    </button>
                    </div>
                    <?php 

                    if ($i%10 == 0):
            echo "<br>";
        endif;  
        }
    }
```

And then I have the "products.php page", where the extracted data is shown:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<section class="wrapper">
<div class="row">
<div class="row-eq-height">
    <?php require("products_backend.php"); ?>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
```

But the output of this is all the products in the DB printed on one line, without any lineshift for every 10th line:

[image]

The image shows the output, however due to the window size, only 11 products are shown, but i keeps going outside the window.

To summarize, I want the output to insert a lineshift for every 10th product printed, and that each row should be inside the  div, like in the manipulated Picture below: (Notice, that in order to create the Picture, I have just copied the output from the row line in order to create the second row, Thus I do not want the same output in the second row as in the first row)

[image]

So what am I doing wrong in my code above?

Comment: Try echo'ing `$i` and `$i % 10` every time, rather than the name of the product. See what happens.

Comment: It counts as it should: 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9 0-1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

the class "col-md-1" looks like a floating div

so to break this floating divs, try this :

```
echo "<br style=\"clear : both;\">";
```

Comment: With the `bootstrap.css` included as my stylesheet, I keeps printing all the results in a single row. However, excluding `bootstrap.css` it prints each output in a single row with a lineshift, and then for each 10th element, an extra line shift is printed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%` moduler to add `div` for after every 10 record;

Updated code :

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
$stmt->execute();

$count = $stmt->rowCount();

if($count > 1){

    $table_row = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $i = 0;

    foreach($table_row as $data) {

        if(($i%10) == 0){ echo "<div class="clearfix"></div>";}
    ?> 
                    <div class="col-md-1 cash_register pants">
                    <button class="table_add" value="Bukser">
                        <h4><?php echo $data['product_name']; ?></h4>
                    </button>
                    </div>
                    <?php 

          $i++; 
        }

    }
```

Comment: It still prints all the results in a single row. I have tried to echo `$i%10` instead of the product_name and the counting seems to work, but the line shift does not.

Comment: i have update my code and put `$i++` at the end of loop

Comment: with the `bootstrap.css` included as my stylesheet, I keeps printing all the results in a single row. However, excluding `bootstrap.css` it prints each output in a single row with a lineshift. I do not know, íf this makes a difference?

Comment: try with  `echo "<div class="clearfix"></div>";` , this may work with bootstrape

Comment: I have to write `echo "<div class=\"clearfix\"></div>"` for the code to work, does that make a difference?
Because writing it like that does not make a difference

Comment: can you give us a URL that we can test by ourselves ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
$stmt->execute();

$count = $stmt->rowCount();

if($count > 1){

    $table_row = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $i = 1;
    echo "<div>";
    foreach($table_row as $data) {
    ?> 
                    <div class="col-md-1 cash_register pants">
                    <button class="table_add" value="Bukser">
                        <h4><?php echo $data['product_name']; ?></h4>
                    </button>
                    </div>
                    <?php 
            if(($i%10) == 0){ echo "</div><div>";}
          $i++; 
        }
       echo "</div>";
    }
```

Comment: I am using bootstrap - maybe I should add the surrounding divs (please see my updated code in the initial question above).
However, it does not work - see link for the output result:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2m0dh3&s=8

Comment: It doesn't seems that you are using bootstrap. Pleas remove the class row from my code as updated now.

Comment: Well , I want it to be using bootstrap - however, having removed the `<div class="row">` from the "products.php" page does not seem to work